# Gradle ssh plugin with nohup

Tags: java, gradle, ssh

I am trying to deploy my Java build to CentOS using Gradle ssh plugin

```
remotes {
    ftc {
        role 'masterNode'
        host = '173.199.123.42'
        user = 'root'
        password = 'myPass'

    }
}

ssh.settings {
    knownHosts = allowAnyHosts
}

task deploy {
    doLast {
        ssh.run {
            session(remotes.ftc) {
                execute 'pkill -f \'java.*chat\'', ignoreError: true
                remove 'build/libs/chat.jar'
                put from: file('build/libs/chat.jar'), into: '/root/test'
                execute 'nohup java -jar /root/test/chat.jar &'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works except it never finish, it get stuck on `execute nohup java -jar /root/test/chat.jar &`

How can I make it to run in background?

Comment: Maybe you could use `screen` for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `nohup` usually involves also redirection of the IO to some file so the file descriptors in the connections can be closed:

```
execute 'nohup java -jar /root/test/chat.jar & &> /tmp/log'
```